# Formatting Output to CSV File Format to Account for Empty Values In Some Rows

Tags: java, csv, file-io, hashmap, bufferedreader

tl;dr: I want to output my `HashMap` in the same CSV file format that I am reading it in.

I want to preface this with: I may be going about this the wrong way. Because I started this thinking one thing and didn't account for this problem I'm having. So I'm trying to make a small application that will give you a random movie to watch depending on what genre you are in the mood for (similarly to Netflix's Max application, but considerably dumbed down). I have a list of movies that I'm going to format myself in CSV format, because I recently wrote some code that reads in values from a CSV file and I didn't have much to alter.

Here is the dilemma: I have read in the CSV formatted file (only a two line sample file), since I know what columns contain what I use a `BufferedReader` to read in line by line storing each value of the delimited value in its own `ArrayList` (I know there is a better way but this is what I came up with for now) I then store each `ArrayList` according to genre into a `HashMap`. Now I want to be able to write back out to the same file at some point to edit it. So movies that have been watched will be removed from the `HashMap` and then overwrite the file, so that when it's read back in next time the movie that was already watched will not be in the file anymore. So the difficulty I am having at this point is formatting the output back out to account for empty spaces in the actual CSV.

So for example, the test file I have only contains two lines where each movie genre has two movies except for drama and comedy. So the file looks like this

`Action,Drama,Sci-fi/Fantasy,Thriller/Suspense,Comedy
Action2,,Sci-fi/Fantasy2,Thriller/Suspense2,`

Just to solidify what output I want/expected; Say I watch Sci-fi/Fantasy2, it was a good movie, but it's gotta go, the output I want once removed is this

`Action,Drama,Sci-fi/Fantasy,Thriller/Suspense,Comedy
Action2,,,Thriller/Suspense2,`

But I know I'm not going to get those results because when I simply read the file then output it back out I get:

`Action,Action2,
Drama,,
Thriller/Suspense,Thriller/Suspense2,
Comedy,,
Sci-fi/Fantasy,Sci-fi/Fantasy2,`

So after getting these results I now realize I didn't plan well enough, and wonder if I'm going about this the wrong way. Does anyone know how to format in the way I described? I tried to find a solution, but after coming up empty handed I deduced that maybe the format I want goes against how a CSV should look, considering some cells in the file would have to be blank. I tried keeping any blank spaces from the file so they would go into the hashmap, but results were the same. I thought about bypassing the output file altogether, but I'm not sure how to save the values I originally read in that go into my map. Any ideas or solutions would greatly appreciated. Here is the class that does all the work:

```
 package rngesus;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 public class ReadWrite {

private static final String[] GENRES = { "Action", "Drama",
        "Sci-Fi/Fantasy", "Thriller/Suspense", "Comedy" };
private static final String NEW_LINE = "\n";
private static final String DELIMITER = ",";
private static final int NUM_OF_COL = 5;
private static final int GENRE_1 = 0;
private static final int GENRE_2 = 1;
private static final int GENRE_3 = 2;
private static final int GENRE_4 = 3;
private static final int GENRE_5 = 4;

private static String moviesFile;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> moviesByGenre;

ArrayList<String> actionMovies;
ArrayList<String> dramaMovies;
ArrayList<String> sciFiFantasyMovies;
ArrayList<String> thrillerSuspenseMovies;
ArrayList<String> comedyMovies;

public ReadWrite() {
    moviesFile = "";
    moviesByGenre = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    actionMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
    dramaMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
    sciFiFantasyMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
    thrillerSuspenseMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
    comedyMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void readAndSortInputFile(String fileOfMovies) throws IOException {

    try {
        BufferedReader buffRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                new File(fileOfMovies)));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = buffRdr.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] lnPtr = line.split(",", NUM_OF_COL);
            int diff = Math.min(lnPtr.length, NUM_OF_COL);
            for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
                if ((i == GENRE_1) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()) {
                    actionMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                } else if ((i == GENRE_2) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()) {
                    dramaMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                } else if ((i == GENRE_3) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()) {
                    sciFiFantasyMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                } else if ((i == GENRE_4) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()) {
                    thrillerSuspenseMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                } else if ((i == GENRE_5) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()){
                    comedyMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        buffRdr.close();
        moviesFile = fileOfMovies;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error: Unable to locate file specified");
    }
}

public void mapMoviesToGenre(){
    moviesByGenre.put(GENRES[GENRE_1], actionMovies);
    moviesByGenre.put(GENRES[GENRE_2], dramaMovies);
    moviesByGenre.put(GENRES[GENRE_3], sciFiFantasyMovies);
    moviesByGenre.put(GENRES[GENRE_4], thrillerSuspenseMovies);
    moviesByGenre.put(GENRES[GENRE_5], comedyMovies);

}

public void initMapToOutput() {

    mapMoviesToGenre();
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(moviesFile);
        fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE);

        for(ArrayList<String> moviesInGenre : moviesByGenre.values()){
            for(String movie : moviesInGenre){
                fileWriter.append(movie);
                fileWriter.append(DELIMITER);
            }
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE);
        }

    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

I don't think that is formatted very well but I have some ignorance on that, to anyone, feel free to edit away. I'm already aware that there must be a better way to store the values read in from the file, but for now I'm focused on solving this other dilemma. But if anyone is willing to point anything else out feel free.

Comment: so much is there to read. ;)

Comment: So after reviewing my post, I realized that maybe I should be storing the values in the CSV before reading to be values by rows instead of values by columns since the output is already doing that. When I run the program again with the unwanted output it formats it back to what it was originally. Which tells me that either the way I'm reading or outputting has to give. I won't be working on this at the moment, can anyone confirm this is actually my problem?

Comment: @Satya Yeah...sorry, I try to be descriptive as possible. My redbull amplified my descriptiveness. Sorry about that ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I worked through it, to whom it may concern. I went ahead and grouped the movies line by line as opposed as to column by column. All I had to do was change the `while` part of my code to this

```
 int index = 0;
        while ((line = buffRdr.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] lnPtr = line.split(",", NUM_OF_COL);
            int diff = Math.min(lnPtr.length, NUM_OF_COL);
            for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
                if ((index == GENRE_1) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()) {
                    actionMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                } else if ((index == GENRE_2) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()) {
                    dramaMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                } else if ((index == GENRE_3) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()) {
                    sciFiFantasyMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                } else if ((index == GENRE_4) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()) {
                    thrillerSuspenseMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                } else if ((index == GENRE_5) && !lnPtr[i].isEmpty()){
                    comedyMovies.add(lnPtr[i]);
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
```

And I now get movies of the same genre on the same line every time, although sometimes in different order, which I assume is due to going into and out of the `HashMap`. If anyone knows a cleaner more efficient way to do this, feel free to share, but I solved my problem for now.